# PHP query that returns a JSON object

Tags: php, mysql, json

What is a simple example of a PHP query against a single table in MySQL that creates a JSON object and returns it?

Comment: You want to do three things: [perform an SQL query](http://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/sql-tutorial-introduction), [convert it to a JSON object](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), and [return it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php).

Comment: The real question is how to convert the result set into a JSON object. Is there a function that will do that?

Comment: `json_encode($array)`

Answer (score 3):

Below example does what you describe. First if runs the query against the DB. Then iterates through the results and puts it in an array ($results), then displays that array as a json object.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM table";

$results = array();

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $results[] = $row;
    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->free();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();

/* print json object*/
echo json_encode($results);
?>
```

The example for retrieving the DB results was found here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

The usage of json_encode, can be found here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: You should change the `content-type` header to `application/json` imho

Comment: Wow. The start I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Was there something else you wanted to know? If not, could you please mark the answer as accepted? @darkbee only if what you want to do with the outcome is directly send it to a browser / client.